# Dump C++ source with merged #includes

Tags: c++, header-files

Is there a tool (or Gcc/Clang flag) that creates a single-header C++ file, from a header file that `#include`s multiple other headers (STL and custom ones)? STL header `#include`s should be left untouched.

For example, given these files:

```
// a.h
#pragma once
#include <my_lib/aa.h>
void baz() {}


// aa.h
#pragma once
void foo(int) {}


// b.h
#pragma once
void bar(float) {}


// master.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <my_lib/a.h>
#include <memory>
#include <my_lib/b.h>
#include <vector>
```

Running the tool on master.h would give this output (whitespace may differ):

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
void foo(int) {}
void baz() {}
#include <memory>
void bar(float) {}
#include <vector>
```

If there are any `#include`s inside `#ifdef`s, they should be dumped as well.

Comment: What could be the use case for such a header?

Comment: `gcc -E master.h` or `clang -E master.h`

Comment: @VTT It is easier to use in projects, because you don't have to add anything to the header search paths, you just #include that single header.
@Sergey With clang that doesn't seem to work…the master.h then includes a lot of lines like `# 1 "<built-in>" 1`, and it also seems to inline the STL headers.

Comment: Then it is a very bad idea, you will still need to add everything to the header search paths to build this merged header, you will need to manually track dependencies and update this combined header when any of the dependencies change, it will be difficult to figure out which headers are actually required by your project so removing something from such a merged header may become problematic. @Sergey `-E` runs preprocessor pass, it does not merge anything.

Comment: @VTT A lot of libraries provide a single-header version, and a lot of people (including me) use them and find that they are a good idea. I'm looking for solutions, not opinions.

Comment: A single-header library (not to be confused with header-only library) and "merged header" you've described seem to be unrelated concepts. Also single-header format is only reasonable while library is relatively small.

Comment: I described a single-header library, using those exact words in my question. The title has the word "merge" because I thought it describes the process (English isn't my native language though). In any case I would not say the concepts are "unrelated". So do you know how to do it? Because I don't think Stackoverflow is the right platform to just discuss the pros/cons of some approach back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [created a script to do this](https://gist.github.com/martinfinke/c474ac992155f29f0f0d871ddd8cd99d).